# Solve $2xyy''-2x(y')^2=(2-x^2)(yy'-2y^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I approach the ODE:
$$2xyy''-2x(y')^2=(2-x^2)(yy'-2y^2)$$
I have solved for $y''$:
$$y''=\frac{2x(y')^2-4yx^2+2x^2y^2+2yy'-x^2yy'}{2xy}$$
and don't know how to continue.

Comment: Hint: Assuming $y\ne 0,$ divide by $y^2$ and let $y'/y=z+2.$ Then $2xz'=(2-x^2)z.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Start using $y=e^z$ to make the equation
$$e^{2 z} \left(\left(x^2-2\right) \left(z'-2\right)+2 x z''\right)=0\implies \left(x^2-2\right) \left(z'-2\right)+2 x z''=0$$ Now, reduction of order $p=z'$ to make
$$\left(x^2-2\right) \left(p-2\right)+2 x p'=0$$ which is separable.